# C++ mapping a variable address?

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
class Texture
{
    public:
        //I need this variable in this format
        float diffuseColor[3];
}
```

But I'd like to make an easier interface than dealing with "diffuseColor[0]" and such, something like:

```
myTexture.color.r = 1.0f; //this is diffuseColor[0]
```

So I'm trying to get a class that works as a shell to the diffuseColor values, something like:

```
class Color
{
    public:
        float *r, *g, *b;
}
```

And in my Texture class:

```
class Texture
{
    public:
        Texture()
        {
            color.r = &diffuseColor[0];
            color.g = &diffuseColor[1];
            color.b = &diffuseColor[2];
        }

        Color color;
    private:
        float diffuseColor[3];
}
```

But the way it is now, I have to de-reference the color values if I want to use them:

```
(*myTexture.color.r) = 1.0f;
```

How can I achieve this without having to de-reference it everytime I want to use it?

Comment: Use references instead of pointers. And move the initialization of the references into the `Color` constructor instead of `Texture`. Or maybe you could just use accessor functions (eg. `r() / r(float)` as getter/setters) and get rid of the `Color` subclass.

Comment: @syam: references instead of pointers won't allow copying.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah right, didn't think about that, my bad (I pretty much always use accessors for this kind of stuff, they're much cleaner IMHO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use references which would be initialized in the member initializer list:

```
struct Color {
    Color(float* colors): r(colors[0]), g(colors[1]), b(colors[2]) {}
    float& r;
    float& g;
    float& b;
};
class Texture {
    float diffuseColor[3];
public:
    Color color;
    Texture(): diffuseColor(), color(this->diffuseColor) {}
};
```

If you need to copy and/or assign `Texture` objects, you'll also need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator. Also note that this convenience has a relatively steep costs: both the pointers and the reference approach will increase the size of the `Texture` objects by 3 pointer. You might be better off to use accessors, instead, e.g.:

```
class Texture {
    float diffuseColor[3];
public:
    float& r() { return this->diffuseColor[0]; }
    float& g() { return this->diffuseColor[1]; }
    float& b() { return this->diffuseColor[2]; }
};
```

Comment: I didn't understand a thing of the Texture constructor but it's working... I got something new to research!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the union language feature of C++:

```
union ColorUnion {
    // first representation (Texture)
    struct TextureColor {
        float diffuseColor[3];
    }

    // second representation (RGB) 
    struct RGBColor {
        float r;
        float g;
        float b;
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that you can't write the `diffuseColor` elements by writing to the named values or vice versa! A union only stores one type at a time and accessing a different type is undefined behavior unless you access a member of a common prefix of the two types.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I thought there was some relaxation of that rule for types who's members are the same.  Maybe that was only for accessing them via pointer or something.

Comment: 9.5/1 "If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. —end note ]"  (Still looking)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, there is a relaxation: when the types have a common prefix, e.g. `union { struct { int a; int b; float c; } s0; struct { int a; int b; double c; } s1; };`: you can access `s0.a` or `s1.a`. However, an array and a named member are not layout compatible (I think; searching the clause).

Comment: @MooingDuck: it is 9.2 [class.mem] paragraph 16: "Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types (3.9)." Now the question becomes if a an array of three `float`s counts as three data members in a `struct` but I don't think so.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I was thinking of going "recursively" down to the primitive objects, but your right that that concept doesn't take the alignment of intermediate structs into account, which means it can't "peek through" the structs.  You're right :D

Comment: You have to spell out the struct name, but when you put the union into a struct, the union can be anonymous. In which case at least you don't have to spell out any name for the union variable.